# Google SAML SSO

Tags: google-cloud-platform, saml, saml-2.0

I'm trying to incorporate Google SAML SSO into my web application, but I'm having trouble finding resources or examples that explain how to do it.

I have followed Google's documentation on SAML SSO, but I'm still having difficulties.

What are the steps required to implement Google SAML SSO into a web application? Are there any libraries or frameworks that can help with the integration?

Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What platform/language does your application use?

Comment: My Application is built on Angular